# Direction field for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to draw a direction field for simpler DE on the form $$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)$$ but I do not understand how I'm supposed to draw a direction field for a DE on the form $$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,t)$$. Take for example the DE $$y'+2ty = 2te^{-t^2}$$
which can be rewritten as $$y' = 2t(e^{-t^2}-y)$$
What are the steps that should be taken to draw a direction field for this?